# how to avoid getView to be called endlessly when invalidating adapter's data?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I want to implement lazy items loading from the server using Android ListView.

For that propose i have added the next code in my Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (position != 0 && position % 7 == 0)
    // ask next page
    {
        mOffersListActivity.getOffersFromServer(ListType.FULL, 10, 10);
    }
```

This calls the hosting Activity which loads the next bulk from the server:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void afterServerOfferResponse(final Gson gson,
        String result) {

    boolean hadError = false;

    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Offer>>() {
    }.getType();

    if (mOffersList == null) {
        mOffersList = new ArrayList<Offer>();
    }
    mOffersList.addAll((Collection<? extends Offer>) gson
            .fromJson(result, collectionType));

    if (mOffersList == null || mOffersList.size() == 0) {
        errorMsg.setText("no offers found");
        hadError = true;
    } else {

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(
                    OffersListActivity.this, mOffersList,
                    listType);
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.invalidate();
    }
```

The problem is that the getView for position 7, 14 and so on is called endlessly

how can I avoid this?

I have thought to put this is the adpater instead of the `%7 code`:

```
if (mOffersList.size() - 3 == position)
        // ask next page
{
    mOffersListActivity.getOffersFromServer(ListType.FULL, 10, 10);
}
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call getOffersFromServer it looks like to reload your adapter, so it will reload th eview as well...

But this approach does no seems correct to me, you will have to maintain an connection open all the time, which is very bad, it is preferable to download all or at least a good chunk of data before showing anything, you will avoid a lot of network overhead and battery waste over constant connection e network calls.